# Send email from my custom mailgun SMTP address

Tags: email, smtp, mailgun

Sorry if I have not understood something but (I believe) I have searched enough for this.

1. First things first: I have successfully set up my domain (`mydomain.gr`) which has been verified.
2. I have created a custom SMTP address (`contact@mydomain.gr`).
3. I have created a route which forwards everything sent at `*@mydomain.gr` to my personal Gmail address.
4. Test 1: If I send an email from an external address (something@something.eu) to contact@mydomain.gr it is forwarded to my personal Gmail. OK!
5. Test 2: If I send from contact@mydomain.gr to any external address (something@something.eu) I get the error `Free accounts are for test purposes only. Please upgrade or add the address to authorized recipients in Account Settings`. Of course the password is correct while sending. Otherwise another error is raised.

I think I have missunderstood some things...

So here comes my question:

How can I send email from my custom SMTP email address? (I do not wish to upgrade my account since this -free- Mailgun account will handle very small amount of emails. So, 10K are more than enough for me.)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

OK. After some emails with the mailgun team I finally figure it out!

All I had to do was to upgrade my account (just enter credit card info). Now I can send email from `contact@mydomain.gr` to anyone.

Thank you mailgun!

Comment: Did you have to change any configuration? Was there a delay from upgrading your account and when you could send emails to everyone? I am having the same issue and recently upgraded my account to a paid account but can't send emails to anyone except authorized emails. I opened a ticket with mailgun, but thought I would also post here in case you have any ideas

Comment: No, I didn't have to change any config. As far as I recall there was no delay to start sending emails. The mailgun team responded to me quite fast so you should get your reply soon!

Comment: I spoke with technical support at Mail Gun today, was super impressed they were answering questions on a Sunday. They told me it should change over in ~5 minutes. The root cause of my problem had to do with the email itself was being treated as spam. I was sending a generic "Hello World" email to 3 emails where 1 of the 3 was an authorized recipient. I had no issues receiving the email at the authorized but the 2 other emails were filtering it out as spam. When I changed the message to be a more realistic example the message was getting through without issue. Hope my findings help someone else

Comment: I also having the same issue. I already upgraded my  account by typing my credit card info but still, I can't send email except to the valid recipients.

Comment: Same issue here, adding a credit card will solve the problem!

Comment: ...yeah, thank you mailgun, they could make it clear somewhere in that beautiful site though :/

Answer (score 0):

I have also contacted Mailgun for the issue and get response back within few minutes:

This error occurs whenever utilizing either a sandbox domain or a free account without inviting users called Authorized Recipients.

Sandbox domains always require Authorized Recipients. With free plans, which are intended for test usage, all custom domains require Authorized Recipients. With upgraded plans, which are intended for production usage, custom domains no longer require Authorized Recipients.

Please take a look at the following Help Center article for more information about the Authorized Recipient process:

https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/217531258-Authorized-Recipients

Then I have add the Authorize Recipients and it works like a champ!

Comment: As you said, correctly, *Sandbox domains always require Authorized Recipients*. However that could be cumbersome for production. Adding a credit card number, will solve the issue (the 10K/month email restriction applies, which in small-medium projects would be sufficient).

Comment: I didn't add any credit card information and email services working fine for me and I can send 10K/month emails, I have implemented on my personal website [link](http://www.syedmuzammilali.com) and even 10K is like unlimited emails for me