# 400 bad request Mailgun Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, mailgun

I am using Mailgun in Laravel. I had previously setup my mailing account with Mailgun and it was working fine but i had to change it for some reason. I have followed the same procedure and that i followed earlier but somehow it isnt working as same. I am using **Laravel 5.0** . My .env file is

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:*****
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=stelp_dev
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=


BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379



MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=postmaster@dev.stelp.pk
MAIL_PASSWORD=*****
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Support RainbowSix"
MAIL_FROM=support@intelrainbow6hub.com


MAILGUN_DOMAIN=dev.stelp.pk
MAILGUN_SECRET=*****



PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_KEY=
PUSHER_SECRET=
```

I have verified domain and added all txt and mx records. But i am still getting this error

```
ClientException in RequestException.php line 111:
Client error: `POST https://api.mailgun.net/v3/dev.stelp.pk/messages.mime` resulted in a `400 BAD REQUEST` response:
{
"message": "Free accounts are for test purposes only. Please upgrade or add the address to authorized recipients in (truncated...)
```

I am adding the screenshot so that you can see i have all things verified as well

[image]

Comment: You've just posted your Laravel APP_KEY to the internet, you'll want to generate a new one.

Comment: Ditto for your mailgun password.

Comment: Yeah you 100% want to take out any passwords etc

Comment: And your mailgun secret key...

Comment: The message gives you the reason for the request failure... what is your question in regards to the message?

Comment: why am i getting this error when i have done everything correctly

Comment: You haven't... read the message. **Free accounts are for test purposes only.**

Comment: yeah i know.. i have added a verified domain.. and perviously i was sending messages via another account with similar configurations..

Comment: It has nothing to do with your domain, it has to do with your account.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42027326/send-email-from-my-custom-mailgun-smtp-address

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send email from my custom mailgun SMTP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42027326/send-email-from-my-custom-mailgun-smtp-address)

Comment: I am getting your point but the thing is i have another account with exact similar details yet i can send mails from it.. why is that so

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a credit card to the account (even if you want to use a free plan). Otherwise you are restricted to sending email to "Authorized Recipients"(look under settings)